# usort on an array call from a database in included file

Tags: php, arrays

I have a database file that executes a query and gives a result:

```
$panelResult = $mysqlConn->query($getPanels);
```

I've included this file in another file and I can loop on it but the issue is I want to first perform a usort on the array. Once it's sorted, then my foreach will come into play. If I hardcode an array then the sort and foreach work fine.

How can I call my mysql result variable as an array to be used in the usort here? Currently I just have an empty array print out obviously

```
  <?php
  $panelResult = [];
  function cmp($a, $b) {
      $goodOrder = [4,6,3];
      return array_search($a["panel_type_id"], $goodOrder) - array_search($b["panel_type_id"], $goodOrder);
  }

  usort($panelResult, "cmp");
  var_dump($panelResult);
  ?>
```

Update:

I'm now using

```
$panelResult = $mysqlConn->query($getPanels);
$data_array = array();
while ($panelRow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($panelResult)) {
    $data_array[$panelRow['panel_type_id']] = $panelRow['content'];
}

function cmp($a, $b) {
   $goodOrder = [4,6,3];
   return array_search($a["panel_type_id"], $goodOrder) - 
  array_search($b["panel_type_id"], $goodOrder);
}

usort($data_array, "cmp");
```

and on my html side
    
    
     ... and so on

But still nothing is showing on page

UPDATE:

New function
    while ($panelRow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($panelResult)) {
      $data_array[$panelRow['panel_type_id']] = $panelRow['content'];
    }

```
function cmp($a, $b) {
    $goodOrder = [4,6,3];
    return  array_search($b["panel_type_id"], $goodOrder) - array_search($a["panel_type_id"], $goodOrder);
}

uksort($data_array, "cmp");
```

Comment: why don't you use `order by` in your sql query?

Comment: Output "on page" needs you to do some `echo` or other output method. It is nowhere in your question's code. Is your question about sorting or about output? Do you get output if you don't sort at all?

Comment: Yes if I just stick with $panelResult = $mysqlConn->query($getPanels); in my db file then I can use my forloop on the other page or just simply var_dump($panelResult) and I can see the mysqli object on the page

Comment: So your desired output is a mysqli object? In that case you should really produce the right order in your SQL query. But honestly, I cannot imagine that outputting a mysqli object structure is a user-friendly format...

Comment: Not necessarily, that's just how it's been but now I need to make sure that any results that come in are sorted in the order of 4,6,3. I just don't have anything else in the database to order it by and there are other pages where it would be a different order. I'm trying to do it page specific

Comment: Please add the output you get from `var_export($data_array);`

Comment: array(3) { [0]=> string(136) " /html/"[1]=> string(136) "[2]=> string(136) "} so it seems to show the content but not the panel_type_id

Comment: Use `uksort` instead of `usort` and then see what `var_export($data_array);` outputs.

Comment: Ok that now outputs the panel_type_id as the key and the html content as the string. So now I wonder, how would I change this for loop to match that?
```<?php foreach($data_array as $PR): 
 if($PR['panel_type_id'] == 4){ ?>```

Comment: You would need to get the key, like `foreach($data_array as $panel_type_id => $content)` and then you have a variable for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you put the `panel_type_id` in the array *key* (not value), and you want to sort by it, you need to use `uksort` (user-defined *key* sort) instead of `usort`.

In your compare function the values of `$a` and `$b` will be the key values, not the arrays, so don't do `$a[panel_type_id]`, but just `$a`. Same for `$b`:

```
function cmp($a, $b) {
    $goodOrder = [4,6,3];
    return  array_search($b, $goodOrder) - array_search($a, $goodOrder);
}
```

Then you can iterate the result like so:

```
foreach($data_array as $panel_type_id => $content) {
    if ($panel_type_id == 4) {
        // ...
    }
    // ...   
}
```

Comment: So this totally fixed my looping problem, thank you! The only issue is I just realized when I var_dump my $data_array it's coming back as '6,3,4' but I set my uksort to be '4,3,6'

Comment: It seems to be doing the order selected by mysql in reverse. Can I not customize the order for uksort?

Comment: That is just a matter of swapping the terms in the subtraction you have in the `return` expression in `cmp`

Comment: I swapped it in my update above but there's no change

Comment: You should not use the `["panel_type_id"]` part in `cmp`, since `$a` and `$b` are *already* keys. So just do `return  array_search($a, $goodOrder) - array_search($b, $goodOrder);`